# Not match the datatypes of the criteria expression ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a update like this in a module of ms access:

```
sql = "ALTER TABLE Carrera "
sql = sql & "ADD COLUMN carrera_nombre TEXT(25);"
Application.CurrentDb.Execute (sql)

sql = "UPDATE Carrera "
sql = sql & "SET Carrera.[carrera_nombre] = '" & strFunction(Carrera.[NombreCarrera]) & "' "
sql = sql & "WHERE Carrera.[CarreraId] > 1000;"
Application.CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
```

In database the column NombreCarrera exist, and I declared the function:

```
Function strFunction(str) As String
    strFunction = str & "test"
End Function
```

But I get the error 3464 Not match the datatypes of the criteria expression, and I don't understand why, the strFunction return a String and the carrera_nombre and CarreraNombre columns type is TEXT.

EDIT: If I check string sql through `MsgBox(sql)` y get the right query: `UPDATE Carrera SET Carrera.[carrera_nombre] = 'mathtest' WHERE Carrera.[CarreraId] > 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe since you declare the sql command as a string, you will have to get it first.
so one of your code

sql = sql & "SET Carrera.[carrera_nombre] = strFunction(Carrera.[NombreCarrera])"

Should become

sql = sql & "SET Carrera.[carrera_nombre] = " & strFunction(Carrera.[NombreCarrera]) & """

Comment: Is a good point and I understand, but I have still a doubt why to the end there is triple double quotes?, If I try with this option I get the error object requeried, I also tried: `"SET Carrera.[carrera_nombre] = '" & strFunction(Carrera.[NombreCarrera]) & "'"`and I get object required.

Comment: the sql itself is a string, but when you call some function to get values you need to add them together? thats why there was a triple quotes. i think i also have some syntax error there.