# How to use a table field as a parameter of a function?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to do something like this in an Access module:

```
sql = "UPDATE Carrera "
sql = sql & "SET Carrera.[carnombre]= '" & strFunction(Carrera.[CarreraNombre]) & "' "
sql = sql & "WHERE Carrera.[CarreraNombre]='ANIMACION';"
MsgBox (sql)
Application.CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
```

but I get the error "has not defined the variable" and has highlighted `Carrera` in `strFunction(Carrera.[CarreraNombre])`. If I use any other string the update works. How to use the field `Carrera.[CarreraNombre]` as a parameter for `strFunction()` that returns a string?

Comment: Post the code for the function, please.

Comment: @OverMind I'm trying to apply a complex regular expression, but the error is reprodycible with this dummy function: `Function strFunction(str) As String
    strFunction = str & "test"
End Function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Carrera.[CarreraNombre]` only has a value when the SQL query is being executed. You are asking VBA to call `strFunction()` while you are building the string, and VBA has no idea what `Carrera.[CarreraNombre]` means. I believe you want to do this:

```vbs
sql = sql & "SET Carrera.[carnombre] = strFunction(Carrera.[CarreraNombre]) "
```

Comment: if I use this approach then I get this problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733463/not-match-the-datatypes-of-the-criteria-expression-ms-access/25734603]

Comment: What data type is `Carnombre`?

Comment: @OverMind it was created as `TEXT(125)`

Comment: @jaundavid You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/501108/jaundavid.zip).

Comment: I don't know why but now it works, seems as if it would magically fixed.